# Making a radio button selected by default and making a textbox unable to take input in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am coding in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and have a form whereby I have two radio buttons and a textbox, that is:

```
o Radio button 1 "Yes"

o Radio button 2 "No"   Textbox here
```

I want the form to load with the "Yes" radio button already selected, that is:

```
x Radio button 1 "Yes"

o Radio button 2 "No"   Textbox here (grayed out "cannot input text")
```

By default, the textbox should not accept input. I want it such that if a user clicks and selects `radio button 2` `"No"`, the text box is now able to accept input.

How do I achieve this?

```
private void rb_taxable_yes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void rb_taxable_no_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `Form` in design mode set `Enabled` to `False` for the `TextBox`, and `Checked` to `True` for the first `RadioButton`.

Attach both radiobuttons to one event handler:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Enabled = radioButton2.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start out with textbox1.enabled = false, and use the onchecked event for the second radio button to change that. also set the first radio button to have radiobutton1.checked = true.

Answer (score 1):

just choose the properties of your radio button 1

and then select the "checked" item as true 
it will set as defult.
no need to code